# Для каждой длины слова найти первые 15 самых часто используемых слов этой длины

Tags: java

У меня есть Map<String, Integer> (где String - это слово, а Integer - это количество использований этого слова в тексте).
Мне нужно для каждой длины слова найти первые 15 самых часто используемых слов
этой длины.
Как это сделать? Никак не могу додуматься. Подскажите ПОЖАЛУЙСТА.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На быструю руку можно так (рефакторинг уже на вашей совести) :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> source = new HashMap<>();
        source.put("xxx", 2);//количество использований в тексте
        source.put("yyy", 3);
        source.put("zzz", 5);
        source.put("aa", 7);
        source.put("bb", 9);
        source.put("cc", 11);

        calculate(source, 2);//по условию задачи 2 нужно изменить на 15

    }

    private static void calculate(Map<String, Integer> source, int numb) {
        create(source).forEach((length, set) -> {
            System.out.println("Length : " + length);
            set.stream().limit(numb).forEach(System.out::println);
        });
    }

    private static Map<Integer, TreeSet<Word>> create(Map<String, Integer> source) {
        Map<Integer, TreeSet<Word>> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (String word : source.keySet()) {
            if (result.containsKey(word.length())) {
                result.get(word.length()).add(new Word(word, source.get(word)));
            } else {
                TreeSet<Word> set = new TreeSet<>();
                set.add(new Word(word, source.get(word)));
                result.put(word.length(), set);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static class Word implements Comparable<Word> {

        private final String name;
        private final Integer number;

        public Word(String name, Integer number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Word word) {
            int compareNumb = word.number.compareTo(this.number);
            return compareNumb == 0 ? this.name.compareTo(word.name) : compareNumb;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + "(" + number + ")";
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо Вам большое

Comment: @Override
        public int compareTo(Word word) {
            int compareNumb = word.number.compareTo(this.number);
            return compareNumb == 0 ? this.name.compareTo(word.name) : compareNumb;
        }
Не совсем понял для сего нужен этот метод

Comment: @Munir в данном решении используется коллекция TreeSet, это не обычная коллекция, она автоматически сортирует свои элементы. порядок сортировки определяется этим методом